# Visual Studio crashes when launching SharePoint add in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2017

My visual Studio 2017 community keeps freezing and i get the error message not responding when i deploy a Provided hosted add in to SharePoint. I can run all other types of projects that i have tried without any problems. I have a newly installed windows with just a few programs on it. I can run a console application to my SharePoint online without any problems. So i guess SharePoint isn't the problem.

[image: Error msg]

What i have tried:

- Reinstall windows
- Reinstall Visual Studio
- Reinstall ISS
- Update Visual Studio
- Update windows
- Disable some debug options (Read online that might help)
- And some minor things

I appreciate any help/tips i can get everything is helpful at this point.

Comment: this is no crash, it is a free/hang. create a dump of devenv.exe when it got frozen (ProcessExplorer) and analyze the dmp with windbg (**!analyze -v -hang**) or [DebugDiag2 Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump)

Comment: I get these errors:
Trying to create a dump https://gyazo.com/395d225fc50c52762e10edac346f2dcd
Trying to open the dmp file https://gyazo.com/a6d82c11b5032328b6e943b65af82676

Comment: the dmp was not successfully created so windbg can't open it. run 32bit taskmgr ("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Taskmgr.exe") (important, because VS2017 is stil 32Bit) and create the dmp here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem and i figure out its firefox problem, so when i uninstall firefox, problem solved for me,
may be it help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, you need to change the default browser from "Start Action" to "Internet Explorer" in the Add-in project properties pane.